# HOW to get $_POST variable into my CLASS?

Tags: php, class, post, private

Probably a newbie question, but then I'm learning on the fly:

Within the following code, I need to name $targetname and $imagelocation come from the $_POST variable coming in... I KNOW I can't define these variables properly the way I'm trying to, but am a bit stumped... help anyone?

```
class PostNewTarget{

//Server Keys
private $access_key     = "123456";
private $secret_key     = "142356";

private $targetName     = $_POST['the_target'];
private $imageLocation  = $_POST['the_image'];

function PostNewTarget(){

    $this->jsonRequestObject = json_encode( array( 'width'=>300, 'name'=>$this->targetName , 'image'=>$this->getImageAsBase64() , 'application_metadata'=>base64_encode($_POST['myfile']) , 'active_flag'=>1 ) );

    $this->execPostNewTarget();

}
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize first your class properties

You can set $_POST values to your class properties when you create your class object using constructor, or you can set just when you need to get these values, I made it in your example

```
class PostNewTarget{

//Server Keys
private $access_key     = "123456";
private $secret_key     = "142356";

private $targetName     =  "";
private $imageLocation  = "";

//you can give class variables values in the constructor
//so it'll be setted right when object creation
function __construct($n){
    $this->targetName = $_POST['the_target'];
    $this->imageLocation = $_POST['the_image'];
}

function PostNewTarget(){
    //or you set just only when you need values
    $this->targetName = $_POST['the_target'];
    $this->imageLocation = $_POST['the_image'];

    $this->jsonRequestObject = json_encode( array( 'width'=>300, 'name'=>$this->targetName , 'image'=>$this->getImageAsBase64() , 'application_metadata'=>base64_encode($_POST['myfile']) , 'active_flag'=>1 ) );

    $this->execPostNewTarget();

} 
}
```

Comment: Putting the values in the functions like that is a completely valid way to do it. However, it greatly impedes the testability of a given class.

Answer (score 3):

Pass into the method:

```
function PostNewTarget($targetName, $imageLocation)
```

Then call with:

```
PostNewTarget($_POST['the_target'], $_POST['the_image'])
```

You could possibly add in the constructor, but I wouldn't:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->targetName = $_POST['the_target'];
    $this->imageLocation = $_POST['the_image'];
}
```

Comment: I'm doing something wrong... possibly I have to show you more of the code -

Comment: I'm doing something wrong... see more of the code -
`    $instance = new PostNewTarget();
   //break;

class PostNewTarget{

 //Server Keys
 private $request;       
 private $jsonRequestObject;
 private $targetName  = $_POST['name'];
 private $imageLocation  = $_POST['location'];
 
 function PostNewTarget(){
  
  $this->jsonRequestObject = json_encode( array( 'width'=>300, 'name'=>$this->targetName , 'image'=>$this->getImageAsBase64() , 'application_metadata'=>base64_encode("test.json") , 'active_flag'=>1 ) );
  $this->execPostNewTarget();
 }
}`

Comment: Edit your question I can't decipher that.

Answer (score 2):

Treat it as a normal variable and put it in a constructor or mutator or argument of a function if it's only needed in that function. Here is an example using a constructor, but the logic is the same in every case.

```
class Example {
    public $varFromPOST;
    public $name

    public function __construct($var, $name) {
        $this->varFromPOST = $var
        $this->name = $name
    }   
 }
```

Then in your index.php:

```
$_POST['foo'] = 100;
$userName = 'Bob';
$Example = new Example($_POST['foo'], $userName);
```

Seems straightforward, if I didn't misunderstand your question.